# rows missing with group by added

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

this is probably something very noob of me

i have the following table

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from_id    | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| to_id      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reply_cost | int(5)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| date       | timestamp   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body       | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| read_      | char(1)     | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| trash      | tinyint(1)  | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| trashDate  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

a select like

```
select id,from_id,to_id,date from mail where to_id='100' order by id desc limit 50;
```

returns

```
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id       | from_id | to_id | date                |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 30071061 | 142     | 100   | 2013-08-15 04:39:56 |
| 30070785 | 282     | 100   | 2013-08-15 02:29:00 |
| 30064666 | 282     | 100   | 2013-08-14 16:10:39 |
| 30042809 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-12 15:50:45 |
| 30042560 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-12 15:28:39 |
| 30042557 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-12 15:28:22 |
| 30022845 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-10 17:32:40 |
| 30022834 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-10 17:31:22 |
| 30018276 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-10 06:09:27 |
| 30018275 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-08-10 06:09:00 |
```

but a select like this

```
select id,from_id,to_id,date from mail where to_id='100' group by from_id order by id desc limit 50;
```

outputs like this (from_id 282 is missing)

```
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id       | from_id | to_id | date                |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 30017678 | 142     | 100   | 2013-08-10 01:56:38 |
| 29928935 | 189638  | 100   | 2013-07-31 18:33:01 |
| 29894382 | 458582  | 100   | 2013-07-27 22:15:53 |
| 29883054 | 409699  | 100   | 2013-07-26 15:22:35 |
```

any idea how this can be avoided ?

EDIT: forgot to mention, the goal is to return only one row per from_id.

Comment: Since you're applying `ORDER BY` clause that behavior is correct. Note, that `ORDER BY` is applied to all result, and, therefore, due to ordering by `id` column, you'll get result as you've written.

Comment: well i simply want to accomplich that only one row "per from_id" is returned

Answer (score 0):

What about the query

```
select id,from_id,to_id,date from mail where to_id='100' order by id, from_id desc limit 50;
```

That should work, hopefully.

Comment: sorryi did not properly mention that i did actually exepect to get only one row per "from_id" ..